# Ok to paint exterior trim of leased building?

Tags: rental-property, business-lease

I have a club that leases a space including a street-facing exterior. There is a small flat awning over the entrance way which is bordered by a metal channel which is about 4 inches square. The paint on this metal trim is flaking off. Am I within my rights to repaint this without the landlord's permission? There is nothing in the lease one way or another about painting the exterior trim or other surfaces. I assume having the "full use" of the property means I can repaint the trim. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this without permission. Ask for permission, you will almost certainly get it.